# jquery toggle one div with same class when div is not in the same code block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very simple problem but I cannot find a solution to this. I have found many references to using .parent(), .next(), .find() but none of them are doing what I expect. Ether all the divs with the same class name are expanding and collapsing at the same time or they do not work at all.

So what I am looking for here is to have the same class names and expand and collapse only the one I click. I have something that is like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="expand">More Details</div></td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="extras" style="display:none;">
        <table>
          <tr><td>Some Data</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="expand">More Details</div></td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="extras" style="display:none;">
        <table>
          <tr><td>Some Data</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
    $(".extras").toggle();
});
```

This will expand and collapse all of them when I only want it to do so on the one that is clicked in the "expand" div to trigger the below "extras" div.

Comment: Not sure why everyone uses classes for this kind of behavior.  `id` is your friend.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're ok with repeating classes and adding extra code to deal with the non uniqueness?  Seems to be a bit of an anti-pattern really

Comment: id's need to be unique causing me to use a class for something that is  not unique. It is thrown into a for loop.

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes, if the HTML is programmatically generated, using ID in combination with `data-*` is a way. But nothing wrong using `class`.

Comment: How are you generating the rows?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've seen too many applications where a single element would end up with 3 or 4 classes that were manipulated in an attempt to work around something that would have been much cleaner using an id

Comment: @Tibrogargan you're missing the point that the code targets a really structured type of HTML and here we're talking tables. data-*>ID is used mostly when the order of element is unpredictable in the DOM and prone to changes. Clumbering the HTML with `data-` and `id` attributes that would much likely look like: `data-targetid="bla1"` and `id="bla1"` and than `bla2`, `bla3` is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".extras").toggle();
});
```

Means:

```
$(this)           // Start from here
.closest("tr")    // go up
.next("tr")       // go to next
.find(".extras")  // find element
.toggle();        // do tha thing
```

Comment: Uggh, i knew it was something simple. I am newish to jQuery and have been struggling with this for a couple hours now. Thank you! This worked. I will mark it correct once it lets me :) Great explanation btw.